# Django filtering based on login details

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-login

I am building a web app that lists courses. I can filter courses based on location and category. However, the next step is to allow users to login and assign courses to their profile. Where I am struggling is filtering courses based on the login credentials. Can it even be done? I cannot find anything on it and I have been searching for days. I'll start with the course provider. A dashboard that filters the course where the login has a foreign key course (there are multiple courses per organisation):

```
class ProviderProfile(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Provider)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
```

Once the user has logged in and clicked on the dashboard view, I would like it to return all the courses associated with the organisation attached to the `ProviderProfile`. The course model has the following in the model: `provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)`. Below is an example of how I am filtering courses in other views like this:

```
class Courses_By_Location(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'courses/course_list.html'
    model = models.Course
    context_object_name = 'courses'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = kwargs.get('location', 'DEFAULT-LOCATION')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return date_screen(
            super().get_queryset().filter(location__gen_local__iexact=
                                          self.location).order_by('date'),
        )

    raw_courses = date_screen(models.Course.objects.all())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['locations'] = location_screen(self.raw_courses)
        context['categories'] = category_screen(self.raw_courses)

        return context
```

This works for filtering by location selected in a form. My approach would be to somehow (this is the bit I'm stuck on) get the organisation that the login is affiliated with and filter for courses under that. There is also an issue with the `LoginRequiredMixin`, without the querysets it works. I am guessing that they are overriding it somehow. Edit: due to request from others I have given the model for the course:

```
class Course(models.Model):

    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)

    title = models.CharField('Course Title', max_length=200,)
    first_line = models.CharField('Address Line: 1', max_length=200,)
    second_line = models.CharField('Address Line: 2', max_length=200,)
    third_line = models.CharField('Address Line: 3', max_length=200,)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=200,)
    post_code = models.CharField('Post Code', max_length=200,)
    course_description = models.TextField('Description')
    date = models.DateField('Date')

    start_time = models.TimeField('Starting time')
    finish_time = models.TimeField('Finishing time')
    duration = models.IntegerField('Number of hours')
    CPD = models.IntegerField('CPD points')
    link = models.CharField('Link', max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories)
    gen_cat = models.ForeignKey(Gen_Categories)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Gen_Location)
    cost = models.FloatField('Cost')
```

Many thanks for taking the time to read through this. I have burnt days in trying to get to the bottom of this. Any pointers on the filter by login credentials and overriding of `LoginRequiredMixin` would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in, the user model instance should be available on the request object. i.e. accessing `self.request.user`.  In your example, the courses may be filtered in the `get_queryset` like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
  return date_screen(
    super().get_queryset().filter(
      username=self.request.user,
      location__gen_local__iexact=self.location
    ).order_by('date')
  )
```

Some details on this can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#attributes-set-by-middleware

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, I have doctored it to filter the courses by the provider, however, it now just says that object has now attribute 'provider'. Here is the code: `def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(username=self.request.user,
                                             provider__provider__iexact=self.provider
                                             ).order_by('date')` I have also uploaded the model incase there is any confusion.